# Retrieve a "Google doc" created file size with the google drive api for ios

Tags: ios, api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the file size of the files saved in a google drive account using the google drive sdk for ios.

There is no issue when the file in google drive is not created with Google Docs, but if the file is created with google doc I can't find the json key/value pair with the size: it does not look like the information is provided... .

If I'm wrong, would appreciate you can direct me where to find the file size of a Google Doc created file.

Thanks,
       dom

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I see the same issue. It seems Google documents aren't treated as normal files with a file size.

Comment: ouch, so there is no solution ? hmm...maybe someone from Google can give us some hope (in the form of "We will update the API and provide this information"). Hope if free... . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Oddly the Google Drive app doesn't show file sizes for any file.

Comment: Google docs are not stored as regular files and so don't have simple sizes to report. Why do you want the size? If you export the file, the size of he resulting export will of course vary with the export format. If you are looking to learn how much of your drive quota a file is using, try looking at the About feed before and after creation.

Comment: For my project, I need the file size for each file stored in Google Drive. Said that...I will find a workaround to it. I was just wondering if this metadata was provided. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments above and my reading of the Google SDK docs... Google Drive SDK API do not provide the size of a file created within google doc.

Few reasons for that:

1) Those file size do not count in calculating the space usage of your google drive
2) A google doc can be exported in different formats and each of them may have a different size, so asking for the file size of a google doc generated file is ambiguous until you export it.

Thanks  rmaddy and  pinoyyid for your comments,

```
 dom
```