# How to get the filesize of document from Doc Picker

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Picker Class (https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#configuration-classes-and-types) to allow users to upload files from their Google Drive account.

I can get various properties of what they've selected, but I cannot seem to be able to get the file size;

eg;

```
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var name = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        var size = ??? [how-to-get-document-file-size]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the property name `fileSize`, as given in Drive REST API v2 - [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations), can be used but is only populated for files with content stored in Drive. It is not populated for Google Docs or shortcut files.

I tried to look for ways on how to get file size too, but it seems that it is currently not available. Google Drive SDK currently do not provide the size of a file created within Google doc and found this SO post - [Retrieve a “Google doc” created file size with the google drive api for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964278/retrieve-a-google-doc-created-file-size-with-the-google-drive-api-for-ios) which is somehow related to your concern.