# Get File Size of Google Drive for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api

I am working on Google Drive API, I done every thing what I suppose to do. Issue is only is to get file size before query to download file, I can get size after downloading but I need to get file size before downloading to restrict file.
Here following I am doing in View Did Load.

```
GTLQueryDrive *query =
[GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

query.q = @"mimeType = 'application/pdf'";
query.pageSize = 1000;
query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

and

```
 (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLDriveFileList *)response
                      error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    NSMutableString *filesString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (response.files.count > 0) {
        [filesString appendString:@"Files:\n"];
        for (GTLDriveFile *file in response.files) {
            [filesString appendFormat:@"%@ (%@)\n", file.name, file.identifier];
            NSLog(@"%@",file.size);
            [filesList addObject:file];

        }
        self.output.hidden = YES;
        [self.filesListTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [filesString appendString:@"No files found."];
    }
```

The `file.size` is returning nil, no response is getting on this.
Can any one guide me how to get file size?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere, You may get only the size of the folder, not its file. The `Google Drive API` doesn't support getting a folder content's (file) size.

Or you have to use additional Framework like `Shinobi team frameworks`.

Answer (score 0):

For files with content stored in Drive, you can use `fileSize`. However, please note that it is not populated for Google Docs or shortcut files as described in [Google Drive API - Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations).

Solution given in this SO post - [Retrieve a “Google doc” created file size with the google drive api for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964278/retrieve-a-google-doc-created-file-size-with-the-google-drive-api-for-ios) might also help.